# Custom Android Widget and Eclipse Intellisense

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, intellisense, widget

I am in the process of putting together a little Android app.  I have created a couple of widgets by extending the ImageView and ScrollView widgets.  The problem that I am having is not with the code itself (i.e. everything runs wonderfully) but rather with the Eclipse "intellisense" in an XML layout.  If I am using the native android widgets, I get the normal eclipse suggestions and all is well.  However, as soon as I add a reference to my widget (i.e.  ) I lose intellisense on my widget AND (more painfully) on all widgets below my widget.  In other words, I don't get intellisense on a  if it exists below my widget.  Again....everything runs, there is no error anywhere, it just becomes insanely slow to program this way.

This is very frustrating as I don't remember all the attributes of the various controls.

Has anyone encountered this or have any suggestions on where to begin trying to solve this?  I don't even know what the correct term in Eclipse to start looking at this.  After 3 days looking off and on, I am at my wits end.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the new ADT 9.0.0 plugin. It has many improvements of the "visual editor". See the [changelog here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)